# How to print AFNetworking request as RAW data

Tags: ios, afnetworking

For debuging purposes I'd want to print whole request body. I'm using AFHTTPClient. printing client gives some information, like headers but post/get params are not there.

IS there a way to do it?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

## Built-in AFNetworking tools

For AFNetworking 1.x, use [`AFHTTPRequestOperationLogger`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperationLogger).

For AFNetworking 2.x, use [`AFNetworkActivityLogger`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworkActivityLogger).

These tools both use the `NSNotification` broadcast by AFNetworking to log request and response data to the console. The amount of information to be displayed is configurable, and they can be configured to ignore certain operations.

## Examination in Xcode without these tools

### HTTP Requests (outgoing data)

If you want to examine the body of an outgoing request, look at the `NSURLRequest`'s `HTTPBody` parameter, which is a property on your `AFHTTPRequestOperation`.

For example, in the method `-[AFHTTPClient getPath:
 parameters:
    success:
    failure:]`, after the request is made, you can type this into the debugger:

`po [[NSString alloc] initWithData:request.HTTPBody encoding:4]`

<sub>*4 is `NSUTF8StringEncoding`, as defined in NSString.h.*</sub>

The `NSURLRequest`'s `HTTPMethod` parameter provides the method (GET, POST, PUT, etc.) as an `NSString`.

### HTTP Responses (incoming data)

When your server responds, your success completion block is passed an `AFHTTPRequestOperation` object (called `operation` by default).  You can:

- `p (int)[[operation response] statusCode]` to see the status code
- `po [[operation response] allHeaderFields]` to see the headers
- `po [operation responseString]` to see the response body
- `po [operation responseObject]` to see the response object (which may be `nil` if it couldn't be serialized)

Comment: I see a great number of up votes: will someone please explain to me how to implement the `HTTP Requests (outgoing data)` portion? I am new to iOS so a bit more detail perhaps. thanks.

Comment: Any solutions for logging/debugging in **AFNetworking 3.x** ?

Answer (score 21):

As of AFNetworking 2.0, you should use [AFNetworkActivityLogger](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworkActivityLogger)

```
#import "AFNetworkActivityLogger.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    [[AFNetworkActivityLogger sharedLogger] startLogging];
    [[AFNetworkActivityLogger sharedLogger] setLevel:AFLoggerLevelDebug];
#endif
    return YES;
}
```

If you are using `3.0` and using *CocoaPods*, you will also need to pull `AFNetworkActivityLogger` from the appropriate branch:

```
pod 'AFNetworkActivityLogger', git: 'https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworkActivityLogger.git', branch: '3_0_0'
```

Answer (score 17):

You should have a look at https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperationLogger with AFLoggerLevelDebug as level of debugging.

```
#import "AFHTTPRequestOperationLogger.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    [[AFHTTPRequestOperationLogger sharedLogger] startLogging];
    [[AFHTTPRequestOperationLogger sharedLogger] setLevel:AFLoggerLevelDebug];
#endif
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: This is great.  I think this is a better choice over my answer if you'll need to do regular HTTP debugging.

Comment: there is a new logger for AFNetworking 2.O : https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworkActivityLogger

Answer (score 1):

For AFNetworking 3.0 to be able to set the level of logging, you need the following:

```c
#import <AFNetworkActivityLogger/AFNetworkActivityLogger.h>
#import <AFNetworkActivityLogger/AFNetworkActivityConsoleLogger.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    AFNetworkActivityConsoleLogger *logger = [AFNetworkActivityLogger sharedLogger].loggers.anyObject;
    logger.level = AFLoggerLevelDebug;
    [[AFNetworkActivityLogger sharedLogger] startLogging];

    return YES;
}
```