# Implicit conversion of a non-Objective-C pointer type 'const char *' to ‘id’ is disallowed with ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5, automatic-ref-counting

I am trying to convert an NSString to a byte array. Then I need to save the byte array in a dictionary. So I do

```
[dict setObject:[plainString UTF8String] forKey: key];
```

But I get the compile error

```
Implicit conversion of a non-Objective-C pointer type 'const char *' to ‘id’ is disallowed with ARC
```

Comment: I am using AFNetwork to send data to Google blobstore. I seem to need byte array to be successful.

Comment: Use NSString or NSData.

Comment: See - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901357/how-do-i-convert-an-nsstring-value-to-nsdata - You can simply convert your string to NSData and you should then be able to pass this to AFNetworing

Answer (score 1):

NSDictionary requires keys/values to be Objective-C objects. Is there a reason you can't use your NSString in the dictionary you are trying to produce?

If you really need just the raw bytes, you will need to box those bytes inside an `NSValue` or `NSData` object.

Comment: I am attempting to solve a bigger question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24747809/using-afnetworking-to-post-both-text-and-multiple-images-to-google-blobstore

Answer (score 0):

if `dict` is an `NSDictionary` you cannot store non-objects. There is a Cocoa data structure `NSMapTable` that can store non-object pointers, or you can wrap the non object data in an `NSData` instance.

I have to question why you want to do this. Why not just store the `NSString` and call convert only when needed?

Comment: I am attempting to solve a more difficult question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24747809/using-afnetworking-to-post-both-text-and-multiple-images-to-google-blobstore