# AFNetworking - Make an HTTP POST to REST, sending a JSON with Base64string image

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, post, afnetworking

I am trying to send a base64 encoded image among some other strings using http POST and AFNetworking. I am trying to send the parameters as an NSDictionary:

```
  NSMutableDictionary *info = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [info setValue:filedata forKey:@"filedata"];
    [info setValue:comments forKey:@"comments"];
    [info setValue:username forKey:@"username"];
    [info setValue:@"jpg" forKey:@"filetype"];
    [info setValue:filename forKey:@"filename"];
```

and POST using AFNetworking:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc]initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    [manager POST:@"https://myurl.com/fileupload" parameters:info progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

However I am not sure what else to do at this point. What am I missing? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following example

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

[manager POST:@"https://myurl.com/fileupload" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData
                                name:@"key name for the image"
                            fileName:photoName mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
} success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: Thank you, however I need to upload all the values. 
`("username=%@&filename=%@&filetype=jpg&filedata=%@&comments=%@") `  How do I include these parameters?

Comment: check this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24747809/using-afnetworking-to-post-both-text-and-multiple-images-to-google-blobstore